# Core data storage - Saving multiple sessions and events

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I am trying to implement core data storage for an iOS application. This data also needs to be fetched to populate another part of the interface.

The goal / structure of the storage system is as follows:

A timer running represents a "Session". While a session is running the user can press multiple buttons (some more than once). When a button is pressed it saves an "event" and the time each event was pressed based on the running timer. For example, *user presses button* - event saved at 01:12 (minuets:seconds).

How should I implement core data storage so as to create multiple Sessions which have coinciding events saved during the session?

Comment: Apple provides detailed documentation explaining this, with diagrams and sample code. For example, [Creating a Managed Object Model](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/KeyConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH30-SW1).

Comment: check https://softwarejuancarlos.com/2015/12/19/swift-2-examples-9-core-data-create-get-update-and-remove-entities/